# Request for deleting your own post to take immediate effect

Tags: feature-request

I just tried deleting a post that I'd inadvertently put onto the wrong stackoverflow sub-site (I put it onto meta by mistake). This seemed to downvote my own question but not delete it. I think a deletion like this should take immediate effect as the result of the action is currently confusing.

Comment: The question seems to be deleted; you only have one other listed in [your profile](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1549918/chris-halcrow).

Answer (score 6):

Deletions do take effect immediately, except in cases where deletion is not allowed (when your question has an upvoted answer, or multiple answers), so your feature already exists.

However, if you aren't familiar with how a deletion works, it might be confusing.  When you delete a post, you will still be able to see the post.  It will look different as it will be in a muted red color to help make it clear the post is deleted, and there will be a banner indicating that the question is deleted and who deleted it.

The reason you can see it is all deletions on the site are "soft" deletions, meaning they are only removed from view.  They will still exist in the database and are still accessible to certain users (yourself, modertors, and 10K users who have a link to the question).

Any rep loss (which wouldn't be applicable on meta) will also be returned once deleted, however it is not immediate.  There is usually a delay of several seconds before you see the rep back.  This is due to server-side caching.